# How should Bone Splinters and Mirrorwing Dragon work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, magic-duels

When playing Magic Duels, my opponent had a [Mirrorwing Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirrorwing%20Dragon%5d) as his only creature and I cast a [Bone Splinters](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBone%20Splinters%5d) on it, sacrificing one of my three creatures.

The following occurred:

1) The game copied Bone Splinters (once) - I assume from Mirrorwing Dragon (the game is non-specific)

2) One of my two remaining creatures was targetted by the Bone Splinters copy and destroyed.

3) I was left with a single creature (of the original 3) and my opponents Mirrorwing Dragon was destroyed.  My remaining creature did not have hexproof or protection from black.

Is this how this should've worked?

Comment: Are you sure one of your creatures was destroyed through a copied bone splinters, and not sacrificed as a result of the original bone splinter cost?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the title and issue with "other" here - the situation you describe is indeed the spell being copied for a creature besides Mirrorwing Dragon.

Comment: @Hackworth I had 3 creatures before I cast Bone Splinters.  One of them was sacrificed to the original casting at the Mirrorwing Dragon.  I had 1 creature left when the exchange was done.  So yes I'm pretty sure.

Comment: What seems odd is that you had a creature left. Bone Splinters should've been copied for each of your creatures. Did the remaining one have hexproof or protection from black or something?

Comment: @Jefromi Nope.  I agree it is very strange.  As commented to the answer, I suspect it's either a bug in my favor (rather than disfavor) or the additional casting cost needed to be spent and my opponent sacrificed the dragon to kill an additional one of my creatures.  I would be curious which (or other possibilities) in case this ever happened in real life.  Can't change the game I guess=)

Comment: @joedragons You might want to edit your question to make it clear exactly what happened and what you're asking. It now sounds like what you actually want to know isn't about what "other" means and whether it includes the dragon, but rather why one creature survived.

Comment: I'm downvoting on the basis of the question being quite unclear. I'll keep an eye out for when it gets edited as Jefromi suggests.

Comment: @Jefromi I'll add an edit but not sure it helps anyone, was mulling deleting.

Comment: Your edit appears to substantially change the meaning/direction of the question. Please just clarify the original question you wanted to ask, and if you want to ask a different question, ask a new question.

Comment: @murgatroid99 If you wish you can just delete it.  I cannot, it says to flag for moderator.  I will come back when I have more time if it's still around.

Comment: I'm not telling you to delete it. People asked for clarification mainly because the title asked about the use of the word "other" but the body asked about an interaction between two cards. So, you just need to clarify what you intended to ask. For now, I'm going to roll back your edit, because it changes too much.

Comment: Identifying the creature that survived by name could provide a clue as to why it survived Bone Splinters, or avoided being a target in the first place. Identifying the names of all of the cards involved is always a good idea.

Comment: Also, you mentioned in a comment on Hackworth's answer that your opponent sacrificed his Mirrorwing Dragon to kill one of your creatures. What allowed your opponent to sacrifice Mirrorwing Dragon? Are you certain that it was sacrificed, and not destroyed by Bone Splinters?

Comment: He said in that comment that it was a guess. I think we can safely say that he is not actually certain. I'm pretty sure that comment was simply expressing a misinterpretation of the answer.

Comment: @murgatroid99 He also mentioned sacrificing the dragon in the third comment on the question (above). If anyone else wants to speculate about what the OP meant, let's take that discussion [to another room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45046/question-discussion) and leave the comments here for requesting clarification or suggesting improvements.

Comment: @Rainbolt I've added #s and commentary to try and clarify.  Murgatroid99's speculation is correct, I was guessing - trying to rationalize how this could have happened besides a bug.  I make the same claim in my edit that got rolledback (or tried to).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you cast a spell on a Mirrorwing Dragon as its only target, that spell will be copied for and target each of your creatures.**

> Whenever a player casts an instant or sorcery spell that targets only Mirrorwing Dragon, that player copies that spell for each other creature he or she controls that the spell could target.

"Her or she" refers to the caster of the spell. See also the first ruling on the gatherer page for Mirrorwing Dragon:

> **The copies are only created targeting creatures that the spell’s controller controls.** Copies are not created for all creatures on the battlefield, and the affected creatures may be controlled by a different player than the controller of Mirrorwing Dragon. Notably, if you cast Murder targeting your opponent’s Mirrorwing Dragon, your creatures will each get a Murder, not your opponent’s.

Alternatively, since you said that "he killed **one of** my creatures*", you may be confusing the creature sacrifice cost of Bone Splinters with its effect. After the sacrifice, however, the spell would still be copied for each of your creatures.

Comment: Ah alright, with that murder example, I'm guessing he had to sacrifice his dragon to kill one of my creatures.  Or there's a bug and I got lucky I even had one creature left.  Thanks, I should have read the gather notes more closely.

Comment: @joedragons In the situation you've described, as far as I can tell (because I don't quite understand it either), your opponent didn't have to sacrifice his dragon, and in fact there isn't even anything that _allows_ him to sacrifice his dragon. Unless there's something you've left out of the description, you are the only one who gets to sacrifice a creature, and you should have had all your remaining creatures destroyed by copies of Bone Splinters.